# Tkinter Bind заголовка вкладки

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, ttk, notebook

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
nb = ttk.Notebook(win)
fr = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(fr, text="Some")
nb.pack()
fr.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e: print("ez gg"))
win.mainloop()
```

Как забиндить функцию на нажатие правой клавиши мыши на конкретный заголовок вкладки?

Так не получается, информации в интернете нет.

Comment: стоит привести воспроизводимый пример кода с нужной структурой

Comment: @splash58, добавил

Comment: воспроизводимый пример - это сто миллионов строк кода, а только проблемный участок. но так все равно лучше :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

делаем bind на сам Notebook, identify и index дадут нам название вкладки, можно проверить по имени, что нужная вам, и выполнить действия

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def event_handler(event):
    if nb.identify(event.x, event.y) == 'label':
        index = nb.index(f'@{event.x},{event.y}')
        print(nb.tab(index, 'text'))   # имя вкладки, например, Some 

win = tk.Tk()
nb = ttk.Notebook(win)
nb.pack()

fr = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(fr, text="Some")

sc = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(sc, text="Second")

nb.bind("<Button-3>", event_handler)
win.mainloop()
```

---

индексом вкладки может служить позиция в формате `“@x,y”`, вот что написано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#tab-identifiers)

> 24.2.5.3. Tab Identifiers The tab_id present in several methods of ttk.Notebook may take any of the following forms:
>
> An integer between zero and the number of tabs.
>
> The name of a child window.
>
> A positional specification of the form “@x,y”, which identifies the
> tab.
>
> The literal string “current”, which identifies the currently-selected
> tab.
>
> The literal string “end”, which returns the number of tabs (only valid
> for Notebook.index()).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

def oncontextaction(event):
    name_of_x_y  = nb.identify(event.x, event.y)
    if name_of_x_y:
        x = event.x
        if 10 <= x < 177 :
            index = 0
            print(f'ПКМ:  {nb.tab(index)["text"]}; index = {index}') #
        if 177 <= x < 342 :
            index = 1
            print(f'ПКМ:  {nb.tab(index)["text"]}; index = {index}')    
        if 342 <= x < 508 :
            index = 2
            print(f'ПКМ:  {nb.tab(index)["text"]}; index = {index}')      


color='#21252b'
win.configure(background = color)
win.resizable(False, False)
sky_color = "sky blue"
gold_color = "gold"
color_tab = "#ccdee0"

#style
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create( "beautiful", parent = "alt", settings ={
        "TNotebook": {
            "configure": {"tabmargins": [10, 10, 20, 10], "background":sky_color }},
        "TNotebook.Tab": {
            "configure": {"padding": [30, 15], 
                          "background": sky_color, 
                          "font":('consolas italic', 14), 
                          
                          "width": 10,
                          
                          "borderwidth":[3]},
                          
            "map":       {"background": [("selected", gold_color), ('!active', sky_color), ('active', color_tab)],
                          "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]}}})
style.theme_use("beautiful")
style.layout("Tab",
                    [('Notebook.tab', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                        [('Notebook.padding', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                            #[('Notebook.focus', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                                [('Notebook.label', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''})],
                            #})],
                        })],
                    })]
                 )
style.configure('TLabel', background = color , foreground = 'white')
style.configure('TFrame', background = color)

nb = ttk.Notebook(win, width=300, height=300)

fr1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
fr2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
fr3 = ttk.Frame(nb)

lb1 = ttk.Label(fr1, text="Tab1")
lb2 = ttk.Label(fr2, text="Tab2")
lb3 = ttk.Label(fr3, text="Tab3")

lb1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
lb2.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
lb3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
fr1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
fr2.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
fr3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

nb.add(fr1, text="Some 1111111")
nb.add(fr2, text="Some 2")
nb.add(fr3, text="Some 3")

nb.pack(fill="both", expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
nb.enable_traversal()

nb.bind("<Button-3>", oncontextaction) 

win.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня динамическое количество вкладок, и они разной длины